# Getting Console output to display from Gallio & xunit.net

Tags: visual-studio, gallio, xunit.net, testdriven.net, console.writeline

Previously when executing unit tests with xunit.net / testdriven.net I could see output written to the console (via Console.WriteLine) displayed in the output window.

I'm now using the Gallio TestDriven.Net runner to execute xunit.net tests (Gallio TestDriven.Net Runner - Version 3.0.6 build 787) - and I'm finding it no longer captures the console output.

Gallio appears pretty configurable, is this something that can be enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Gallio v3.1.